# View the size of a filtered ngRepeat array before filtering again with limitTo

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, pagination

I'm currently paginating my `ngRepeat` through a combination of a custom `startAtIndex` filter and a `limitTo` filter. I want to display the total number of results in the data set regardless of the page. However, when you use `limitTo`, this obviously chops the array off at that point, and you can't get the length property you want.

My `ngRepeat`:

```
ng-repeat-start="colleague in pagination.filteredData = (colleagueDataArray | filter:{name: queries.name} | filter:{client: queries.client} | filter:queries.generalQuery | orderBy:sortByField:reverseSort | startFrom: pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo:pagination.pageSize)">
```

I assign the results of the filter to the `pagination.filteredData` object, I can then display it's length anywhere in my controller with `{{pagination.filteredData.length}}`.

How can I go about this to get the length of the filtered array before it's filtered by `startAtIndex` and `limitBy`? Can I somehow partially filter the `colleagueDataArray` array, and then filter the resulting `filteredArray` again with the `ngRepeat`?

If this makes no sense to you, please let me know so I can edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom filter, whatever you are trying there.

```
ng-repeat="data in bigData | filter:myfilter"

$scope.myfilter= function(data)
{
    // Check length or i dont know
    // $scope.bigData.length 

    if($scope.bigData.length > 2)
    {
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }

    return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
};
```